# find ID3 tag information from .aac(m4a) file format in java

Tags: audio, metadata

above in formation is cool for MP3 file can anybody have little idea about .aac format encoding style so i can get metadata information.

Answer (score 1):

What programming language are you using? Do you just want a spec? http://www.danhinsley.com/metax/metax.html is this link the sort of utility you're looking for? mp4 is a common container for aac format content.

Java libraries for interacting with AAC (including tags) include:

http://www.fightingquaker.com/myid3/

http://jid3.blinkenlights.org/

http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/

Comment: for android purpose i want to build that sample code which find tag data for .aac audio file format

Comment: Edited my post to reflect your needs.